# Automating Tortoise SVN Update Fails While User Execution Succeeds

Tags: batch-file, svn, scheduled-tasks, tortoisesvn

I have a few files i want to make sure I keep up to date using Tortoise SVN.  I've used commandline and also created a batch file and both run successfully when I user-execute them.

However, when I use Windows Task Scheduler to try and schedule an automation for the batch script, it doesn't run successfully; it just hangs and runs endlessly.  The log file looks just the same whether using the automation or not.  That said, I have to manually end the automation in task scheduler and then run an SVN cleanup command to remove the locks that remain on the file from the incomplete task.

What is causing this, and how do I make it so that the automation successfully runs and doesn't have the file-locking problem?

My back script's code is below:

```
    svn update --accept theirs-conflict C:/MyFolder/myfile.R
```

For transparency, I've tried changing the option 'theirs-conflict' to other settings (and removing it completely).  The symptoms are the same in every scenario.

Comment: Is `svn update --accept theirs-conflict C:/MyFolder/myfile.R` the whole batch code?

Comment: Which log file? Which locks?

Comment: @MichaelS @royalTS That's the heart of the code, though there are two notable changes I excluded for brevity here:  
1)  In the actual code I'm using , there's an earlier line referencing a log file:
        `echo [%date% - %time%] Log start > C:/MyFolder/myLog.txt`
2) The output of the svn update command is dumped to that file. So, the full line reads:  
`svn update --accept theirs-conflict C:/MyFolder/myfile.R  >> C:/MyFolder/myLog.txt 2>&1`

It works on the commandline just fine, but not when I try to turn that simple command into a batch file.